# authentication failed for git

Tags: git, github

I am using the GitHub desktop application for my version control requirements and everything works fine there.
But when I tried to pull/push from the command line or android studio I am getting authentication errors.

On the command line, it asked for credentials

*Username for 'https://github.com': abc.a@abc.net*

here abc.a@abc.net is my git email

then it asked for a password

*Password for 'https://abc.a@abc.net@github.com':*

'https://abc.a@abc.net@github.com' but it asked for domain GitHub but my email is abc.a@abc.net
I think this is causing the issue but I m not sure.

Note - I am able to login in GitHub with these credentials and also Github desktop is also working fine with these.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, you cannot use your email account to use as a simple HTTPS authentication mechanism to GitHub. Since you *do* have a github account you must have a github username! If your SO profile is correct, it should be `nikhilbansal064` (concretely speaking).

Use your username as the input towards GitHub.

```
Username for 'https://github.com': nikhilbansal064
```

If you don't want to use this form of login towards GH, there are [other options](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-authentication-to-github#authenticating-with-the-command-line) and even a [command line tool](https://cli.github.com/) from GitHub!